# Что означает "распарсить" в python и как это сделать?

Tags: python

Сталкиваюсь с полным непонимаем, как превращать такие строчки (получаю путем `print(a)`, где a - это именно такая строка с данными) - во что то удобоваримое для использования. Соотвественно вопрос - во что можно превратить такие данные и как чтобы было быстро по скорости и удобно для чтения. И каким образом можно вывести например данные с 'supply'? `print(a['supply'])`- не помогает.

```
[{'info': {'id': 176567821', 'ch': 'yes', 'supply': '32', 'store': '2'}, 'timestamp': 1633525912680, 'cost': None}, 
{'info': {'id': 176567824', 'ch': 'yes', 'supply': '14', 'store': '2'}, 'timestamp': 1633525912680, 'cost': None}
{'info': {'id': 176567829', 'ch': 'yes', 'supply': '21', 'store': '1'}, 'timestamp': 1633525912680, 'cost': None}]
```

Comment: Не нужно преобразовывать это в строку, это json формат, нужно работать с ним. Как вы получаете эти данные?

Comment: Получаю их по api. Как из них вытаскивать на ходу какое то значение или серию значений тоже не понимаю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда вы получаете данные от api, то можно сразу получить json, например так:

```py
import requests
r = requests.get(url).json()
```

Конкретно по вашему примеру, то у вас либо лишние кавычки, либо вы наоборот что-то убрали, судя по всему там где значение `id`, там у значения не должно быть кавычек. Данный список представляет собой набор словарей. Циклом мы перебираем список и по ключу извлекаем значение из словаря.

```py
a = [{'info': {'id': 176567821, 'ch': 'yes', 'supply': '32', 'store': '2'}, 'timestamp': 1633525912680, 'cost': None}, 
{'info': {'id': 176567824, 'ch': 'yes', 'supply': '14', 'store': '2'}, 'timestamp': 1633525912680, 'cost': None},
{'info': {'id': 176567829, 'ch': 'yes', 'supply': '21', 'store': '1'}, 'timestamp': 1633525912680, 'cost': None}]

for x in a:
   print(x['info'], x['timestamp'], x['cost'])

for x in a:
   print(x['info']['supply']) # конкретно для supply
```